# Speed control on video strip adds black frames at the end of sequence

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, audio

I'm using Blender to edit and put together short timelapse style video with voiceover. I've put the voice strips first and now I'm adding pre-rendered timelapse clips, which I need to stretch or shorten a bit to match the voiceover.

I chose the method, where I put in pre-rendered clip, apply speed control effect strip with *Stretch to input lenght* checked, which manages auto-adjust its speed after resizing the strip. But every time I do this, on the end of the strip, the few last frames are black.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Did you select-highlight the video strip before adding Speed Control?

Comment: I am back again. Whenever I see black frames at the end of video clip, I would duplicate the clip, return to the original clip and use the Hard Cut to chop off a part of clip with black frames. Press X to delete that unwanted part of strip. Next, go to duplicate clip and use Hard Cut to chop it into two strips. Remove former part of superfluous frames and join the remaining part to the end of the revised original. That is what I often do for motion graphics. If you are unfamiliar with the Hard Cut, see this video tutorial. https://youtu.be/Pw-GPKEMNxY

Comment: Check out this playlist of 17 videos on video editing by Mikeyal Meyers. Tutorials might be little old, but VERY USEFUL. Just browse through the list and you find something you need. Good luck. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjyuVPBuorqIZOWRDICIZ2WCFapHHYLPv

Comment: Btw, the black frames at end sometimes show up, whenever you use Speed Control. I get that problem a lot. Suggestion: delete the faulty clip. Import again the movie clip and duplicate that, that is, BEFORE ever using Speed Control. If you have trouble in duplicating, just import same clip again. Two copies. Play with Speed Control and Hard Cut.